# How exactly does this bit masking (0xffffff & color) works?

Tags: java, bitmask, bitwise-and

And finally I ended up asking here!

There is an accepted answer for converting `int` color to `HEX String` from somewhere from this site.

There is this line in the answer and I was kind of lost figuring it out on my own.

```
String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & anyColor));
```

I'm lost there where this part "bit masking" comes in the above code.

Here is what I've learned so far:

An `int` color is 32-bits `int` with ARGB information in it.

So in the above "bit masking" process, how is the Alpha channel is masked out from RGB part?

What I've tried on my own so far is:

Let's say the above anyColor has this  ARGB values with argb(250, 25, 50, 75).

For the RED channel , and with above code kicks in;
bit masking is first done like this ?

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1001
```

bit masking with `0x0000ff`

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111   1111
```

OR the RED channel is first shifted left from its original int color value and bit masking is apply on it thereafter like this?

RED `<<` 16

```
0000 0000 0001 1001 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

And the bit masking then?

```
             F    F
0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

OR, bit masking done all RGB channels at once with 0xFFFFFF?

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

What I would like to know is what exactly is bit masking done there? Any great explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OR, bit masking done all RGB channels at once with 0xFFFFFF?
>
> ```
> 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
> ```

That's correct.

An ARGB color is encoded, in binary, in the following form:

```
AAAA AAAA RRRR RRRR GGGG GGGG BBBB BBBB
```

where each of the letters represents one bit of the respective component.

The masking in question is with `0xffffff`, which is 8 bits of zeroes followed by 24 bits of ones:

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

By performing a *bitwise* AND of the mask and the ARGB color, the RGB representation is created:

```
0000 0000 RRRR RRRR GGGG GGGG BBBB BBBB
```

Comment: Would be much apprecited if you can give me a line of code or two for the sake of understanding more on it, regarding "By performing a bitwise AND of the mask and the ARGB color"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MyoKo the only line of code that I can really give is the one you already had in your question, namely the expression `(0xFFFFFF & anyColor)`.